# Is "this **type of** work" idiomatic?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idiomatic-language

I've read lots of posts that talk about "type of", "sort of" and  "kind of".

This post focuses on a particular scenario rather than a general discussion.

I guess the following expression is idiomatic.

> Most of my time is spent experimenting with different designs and ideas and seeing what
>   looks good, because attention to detail is important in this **kind of** work.

I got a sense that **kind of work** is a very commonly used expression and other 2 expressions seem not that commonly used. So, is it still idiomatic if I substitute "type of" for "kind of"

> attention to detail is important in this **type of** work

or substitute "sort of" for "kind of"

> attention to detail is important in this **sort of** work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think in pretty much all cases, "kind of *(something)*", "type of *(something)*", and "sort of *(something)*" are all interchangeable, with no real change of meaning, and all are idiomatically about the same.

I think in some cases "kind of" can feel a bit less formal than the others, and I suspect is the most often used of any of them in casual speech, but it's not a really strong difference.  Using "sort of" or "type of" are both common too, even in casual speech.

"type of" also as slightly more of a feeling that there might be a formal categorization of types of items that's being used, whereas "sort of" and "kind of" both have a bit more of a feel of "generally similar to" without necessarily any defined "types".  But again, this isn't a strong distinction, and "type of" is often used for things with no particular defined "types" too.

Note: "kind of" and "sort of" are also interchangeable when used in the sense of "it is (kind of/sort of) **like** *(something)*", but "type of" is *not* interchangeable in that case. (You can't say "type of like *(something)*".  That's ungrammatical.)